# Boolean operation problem with child object after save / load

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am learning blender.  I made a boolean operation as you can see in the screenshot.  Everything works fine and i can save and load back what i did properly as long as the cylinder object is not a child of the cube.

When the cylinder is a child of the cube, the boolean operation is not displayed after i save and reload that file.  Am i doing something wrong ?

I want the cylinder to be a child of the cube so it always moves with it in translations.  If the cylinder is not a child of the cube, then everything works fine but it's not what i want.

Before closing blender, what i see when i save:
[image: screenshot before closing]

After opening blender and reloading the file i just saved:
[image: screenshot after loading]

Comment: The object is still there, you will have to refresh the scene, move the object or frame, I assume that's because when the file is opened the cylinder loaded after the root object and the modifiers.

Comment: Other than moving the object or frame, is there another way to refresh the scene ?

Comment: I see, in the outliner, you didn't apply the Boolean modifier, right?

Comment: It is active, but i have not applied it.  i do not want to modifiy the mesh until i am really sure.  Maybe this is not the proper way of working but i'd like to create many shapes with boolean modifiers and only apply them after i get a look at the whole scene.